# OTP verification failing on Flutter iOS build Webview. But works fine at other webviews rendered using Flutter-Andoid, Native Android, Swift iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview, payment-gateway

We are implementing Card Payments. For card authorization, an OTP screen is rendered using iframe(provided by a Payment Gateway) in WebView

After submitting the OTP on rendered webview...

- **verification is hindered** in the Flutter iOS build.
- verification works fine at Flutter Android build and Native Android build

**Unable to identify why verification fails only in iOS build webview. Appears to us that some issue with the webview which is generated by flutter for iOS build.**

Sharing here code being used for rendering WebView. IFrame is received at `initialUrl`

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:pspsdk/api_services/api_provider/add_bank_provider.dart';
import 'package:pspsdk/config/BuildConfig.dart';
import 'package:pspsdk/config/rtp_constant.dart';
import 'package:pspsdk/models/enum/WebViewType.dart';
import 'package:pspsdk/spl/utils/locale/strings.dart';
import 'package:pspsdk/utils/utils.dart';

class CommonWebViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? url;
  final String? title;
  final String? txnId;
  final String? appLang;
  final String? bic;

  final WebViewType? type;

  const CommonWebViewScreen(
      {Key? key,
      this.url,
      this.title,
      this.txnId,
      this.type,
      this.appLang = 'en',
      this.bic = ""})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  CommonWebViewScreenState createState() => CommonWebViewScreenState();
}

class CommonWebViewScreenState extends State<CommonWebViewScreen> {

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;

  String? initialUrl;
  String? bodySent;
  var _counter = 0;
  Uint8List body = Uint8List.fromList([]);
  Map<String, dynamic> bodyJson = {};

  // Map<String, dynamic> bodyJson = {};
  int statusCount = 0;
  int danaCount = 0;
  bool isStatusCallsStopped=false;

  void checkForStatus() {
    AddBankRepoImp().checkForStatus(widget.txnId!).then((value) {
      print("ulllu");
      print(value);
      if (value['txnStatus'] == 'SUCCESS') {
        Navigator.pop(context, value);
      } else {
        if (!isStatusCallsStopped && statusCount < 90) {
          statusCount++;
          Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
            checkForStatus();
          });
        } else {
          Navigator.pop(context, [false, bodyJson]);
        }
      }
    });
  }
stopStatusCalls(){
    setState(() {
      isStatusCallsStopped=true;
    });
}
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialUrl = widget.url;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      AndroidInAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
          .then((value) async {
        var swAvailable = await AndroidWebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(
            AndroidWebViewFeature.SERVICE_WORKER_BASIC_USAGE);
        var swInterceptAvailable =
            await AndroidWebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(
                AndroidWebViewFeature.SERVICE_WORKER_SHOULD_INTERCEPT_REQUEST);
        if (swAvailable && swInterceptAvailable) {
          AndroidServiceWorkerController serviceWorkerController =
              AndroidServiceWorkerController.instance();
          serviceWorkerController
              .setServiceWorkerClient(AndroidServiceWorkerClient(
            shouldInterceptRequest: (request) async {
              print(request);
              print("request.url");
              return null;
            },
          ));
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("widget.type");
    print(widget.type);
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        showDialog(context: context, builder: (builder)=>AlertDialog(
          title: Text(
              RTPUtils().getTranslation(Strings.Confirmation,
                  context,
                  widget.appLang??"id")),
          content: Text(RTPUtils().getTranslation(Strings.Are_you_sure,
              context,
              widget.appLang??"id")),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text(RTPUtils().getTranslation(Strings.No, context, widget.appLang??"id"))
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  stopStatusCalls();
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text(RTPUtils().getTranslation(Strings.Yes, context, widget.appLang??"id"))
            ),
          ],
        ));
        return Future.value(true);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          backgroundColor: RtpConstant.backgroundColor,
          appBar: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              title: Text(
                widget.title!,
                style:
                    const TextStyle(color: RtpConstant.primary, fontSize: 18),
              ),
              leading: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  showDialog(context: context, builder: (builder)=>AlertDialog(
                    title: Text(
                        RTPUtils().getTranslation(Strings.Confirmation,
                            context,
                            widget.appLang??"id")),
                    content: Text(RTPUtils().getTranslation(Strings.Are_you_sure,
                        context,
                        widget.appLang??"id")),
                    actions: [
                      TextButton(
                          onPressed: (){
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Text(RTPUtils().getTranslation(Strings.No, context, widget.appLang??"id"))
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                          onPressed: (){
                            stopStatusCalls();
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Text(RTPUtils().getTranslation(Strings.Yes, context, widget.appLang??"id"))
                      ),
                    ],
                  ));
                },
                child: Icon(
                    Platform.isIOS ? Icons.arrow_back_ios : Icons.arrow_back),
              ),
              backgroundColor: RtpConstant.white),
          body: getWebView(context)) //put your body container here.
      ,
    );
  }

  Widget getWebView(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: RtpConstant.white,
              border: Border.all(color: RtpConstant.transparent),
            ),
            child:
                // WebViewWidget(controller: webViewController1!)
                InAppWebView(
                    implementation: WebViewImplementation.NATIVE,
                    initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(initialUrl!)),
                    onCreateWindow: (controller, s) async {
                      print('URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(initialUrl!))');
                      print(URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(initialUrl!)));

                      webViewController = controller;
                      return true;
                    },
                    onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) async {
                      webViewController = controller;
                      print("onConsoleMessage");
                      print(consoleMessage);
                      if (consoleMessage.message
                          .contains('merchant callback cimb')) {
                        // if(Navigator.canPop(context)){
                        Navigator.pop(context,true);
                        // }
                      }
                    },
                    iosShouldAllowDeprecatedTLS: (controller, challenge) async {
                      print("iosShouldAllowDeprecatedTLS");
                      webViewController = controller;
                      return IOSShouldAllowDeprecatedTLSAction.ALLOW;
                    },
                    onReceivedClientCertRequest: (controller, challenge) async {
                      print("onReceivedClientCertRequest");
                      webViewController = controller;
                      return ClientCertResponse(
                          action: ClientCertResponseAction.PROCEED,
                          androidKeyStoreType: "",
                          certificatePath: "");
                    },
                    onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest:
                        (controller, challenge) async {
                      print("onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest");
                      return ServerTrustAuthResponse(
                          action: ServerTrustAuthResponseAction.PROCEED);
                    },
                    shouldOverrideUrlLoading:
                        (controller, navigationAction) async {
                      print('in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading--->>>');
                      webViewController = controller;
                      var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;
                      final url = uri.toString();
                      body = navigationAction.request.body ??
                          Uint8List.fromList([]);

                      if (url.contains('merchant-callback-cimb')) {
                        print('---popping the webview!!!---');
                        Navigator.pop(context,true);
                      }
                      print('shouldOverrideUrlLoading--->>>$url');
                      print("shouldOverrideUrl${uri.host}");
                      return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                    },
                    initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.RECOMMENDED,
                        cacheEnabled: true,
                        javaScriptEnabled: true,
                        useShouldInterceptAjaxRequest: true,
                        javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically: true,
                        clearCache: true,
                        useShouldInterceptFetchRequest: true,
                        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
                        useOnLoadResource: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, url) {
                      print("ON LOAD START");
                      print("URL$url");
                      webViewController = controller;
                    },
                    androidShouldInterceptRequest: (controller, request) {
                      webViewController = controller;
                      var url = request.url;
                      if (url.path.contains("notify-binding") ||
                          url.path.contains("notify-payment")) {}
                      return Future.value(WebResourceResponse());
                    },

                    onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {
                      print("onLoadError");
                      print("URL$url");
                      print("message error--->>>$message");
                      // RTPUtils.hideLoading(context);
                      Navigator.pop(context, [false, message]);
                    },
                    shouldInterceptAjaxRequest: (controller, ajaxRequest) {
                      print("shouldInterceptAjaxRequest");
                      print(ajaxRequest.status);
                      return Future.value(ajaxRequest);
                    },
                    shouldInterceptFetchRequest: (controller, fetchRequest) {
                      print("shouldInterceptFetchRequest");
                      print(fetchRequest.body);
                      return Future.value(fetchRequest);
                    },
                    onLoadHttpError:
                        (controller, url, statusCode, description) {
                      print(statusCode);
                      print("onLoadHttpError");
                      print("URL$url");
                    },
                    onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, url) async {
                      webViewController = controller;
                      if (url != null) {
                        print("url_in${url.path}");
                        if (widget.type == WebViewType.ADD_ACCOUNT) {
                          print('apun idhar hai--->>>');
                          if (widget.bic == "BDINID") {
                            if (url.toString().contains("error=")) {
                              print('we are here--->>>');
                              print(danaCount);
                              if (danaCount <= 3) {
                                danaCount++;
                                RTPUtils.showToast(
                                    url.toString().split('error=')[1], context);
                              } else {
                                print('we are here--->>>else');
                                print(danaCount);
                                RTPUtils.showToast(
                                    'Binding request has failed,Please try again later!',
                                    context);
                                // Navigator.pop(context);
                                Navigator.pop(context,true);
                              }
                            } else if (url.toString().contains('auth_code=')) {
                              print('success case--->>>');
                              Navigator.pop(context,true);
                            }
                          }
                          if (url.path.contains("notify-binding")) {
                            print(_counter);
                            if (_counter == 0) {
                              _counter++;
                              print("url-contains " "$url/${widget.txnId}");
                              print("DATA POST IN NOTIFY BINDING");
                              postData(controller, url);
                            } else {
                              // Navigator.pop(context, [true, bodyJson]);
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        else if (widget.type == WebViewType.PAYMENT) {
                          print("url payment");
                          print(url);
                          if (widget.bic == 'BDINID') {
                            if (url.toString().contains("/payment")) {
                              print('we are here--->>>payment');
                              Navigator.pop(context,true);
                            }
                          }
                          if (url.path.contains("notify-payment")) {
                            if (_counter == 0) {
                              _counter++;
                              print("url-contains " "$url/${widget.txnId}");
                              print("DATA POST IN NOTIFY BINDING");
                              postData(controller, url);
                            } else {
                              // Navigator.pop(context, [true, bodyJson]);
                            }
                          } else if (url.path.contains("notify-binding")) {
                            if (_counter == 0) {
                              _counter++;
                              postData(controller, url);
                            } else {
                              // Navigator.pop(context, [true, bodyJson]);
                            }
                          } else if (url.path.contains("landing-page")) {
                            Navigator.pop(context, [true, bodyJson]);
                          } else if (url.path.contains("pws")) {
                          } else {
                            // Navigator.pop(context, [true, bodyJson]);
                          }
                        }
                        else if (widget.type == WebViewType.PAYMENT_CARD) {
                          if (url.path.contains("FINISH_URL")) {
                            postData(controller, url, canPop: true);
                          } else {
                            checkForStatus();
                            print("url payment->${url.path}");
                            print(url);
                            if (url.path.contains("notify-payment")) {
                              if (_counter == 0) {
                                _counter++;
                                print("url-contains " "$url/${widget.txnId}");
                                print("DATA POST IN NOTIFY BINDING");
                                postData(controller, url, canPop: false);
                              } else {
                                // Navigator.pop(context, [true, bodyJson]);
                              }
                            } else if (url.path.contains("notify-binding")) {
                              if (_counter == 0) {
                                _counter++;
                                print("url-contains " "$url/${widget.txnId}");
                                print("DATA POST IN NOTIFY BINDING");
                                postData(controller, url, canPop: false);
                              } else {
                                // Navigator.pop(context, [true, bodyJson]);
                              }
                            } else if (url.path.contains("landing-page")) {
                              Navigator.pop(context, [true, bodyJson]);
                            } else if (url.path.contains("pws")) {
                            } else {
                              // Navigator.pop(context, [true, bodyJson]);
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        else if (widget.type == WebViewType.ADD_CARD) {
                          print("url payment");
                          print(url);
                          // await Future.delayed(
                          //   Duration(seconds: 13)
                          // );
                          // print(
                          //     "url-contains " + "$url/${widget.txnId}");
                          // Navigator.pop(context, [true, "Success"]);
                        }
                      } else {
                        Navigator.pop(context, [true, bodyJson]);
                      }
                    }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  postData(InAppWebViewController controller, Uri url,
      {bool canPop = true}) async {
    bodyJson = getQueryParameters(body);
    // create query string
    var query = bodyJson.entries.map((e) => '${e.key}=${e.value}').join('&');

    if (query.isNotEmpty) {
      Uri requestUrl = Uri.parse("$url/${widget.txnId}?$query");
      print("requestUrl");
      print(requestUrl);
      controller
          .postUrl(url: requestUrl, postData: Uint8List.fromList([]))
          .then((value) {
        print("DATA POSTED");
        if (canPop) Navigator.pop(context, [true, bodyJson]);
      });
    } else {
      Uri requestUrl = Uri.parse("$url/${widget.txnId}");
      print("requestUrl");
      print(requestUrl);
      controller
          .postUrl(url: requestUrl, postData: Uint8List.fromList([]))
          .then((value) {
        print("DATA POSTED");
        if (canPop) Navigator.pop(context, [true, bodyJson]);
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, String> getQueryParameters(Uint8List data) {
    String? dataString = utf8.decode(data);
    dataString = "${BuildConfig().getRtpBaseUrl()}?$dataString";
    return Uri.parse(dataString).queryParameters;
  }
}
```